# Replace With Next Largest Number

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, loops, sorting

I need to write a function that replaces each number with the next highest number in the list.

Say we have the list`[5, 7, 3, 2, 8]`.
The `5` gets replaced by the `7` and the list becomes `[7, 5, 3, 2, 8]`.
After that, we switch the `5` and the `8` so it becomes `[7, 8, 3, 2, 5]`. Eventually the max of the entire list gets replaced by `-1`.
 By the end this example should output `[7, 8, 5, 3, -1]`. I wrote this code:

```
def replace_next_largest(lst):  
    maxes = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        check = lst[i]
        next_mx = [i for i in lst if i > check and not i in maxes]
        if next_mx:
            maxes.append(next_mx[0])
        else:
            if maxes.insert(lst.index(max(lst)),-1 ) 
    return maxes
```

but it does not work with the input `[4, 1, 6, -7, -8, 2]`, but it works for the other list mentioned above and all the other tests. My output is `[6, 4, -1, -1, 1, -7]` and it should be 
`[6, 2, -1, 1, -7, 4]`

`[6, 4, -1, -1, 1, -7]` <--- My Answer

`[6, 2, -1, 1, -7, 4]` <--- correct answer

It works with `[5, 7, 3, 2, 8]` , `[2, 3, 4, 5]`, and `[1, 0, -1, 8, -72]`

Comment: Have you tried changing variable `i` in your list comprehension?

Comment: Are numbers guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @Marat Yes they are

Comment: What do you mean `next highest number`?

Comment: More specifically what do you mean by `next`. Do you mean next as in larger and further to the right. Or next: the next larger, but closest in value in the whole list? Based on your desired result, I think you mean the second.

Comment: Also, how is it ever possible that last element in the answer is not `-1`? Shouldn't that always be the case?

Comment: What is exact problem formulation? Replacing does not assume swaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your desired result, you can sort the list, then do a lookup that finds pairs the numbers with the next largest. With that you can just replace the items in the list. By zipping the values as pairs, the greatest value will not have an entry. You can use this to replace it with `-1` when you try to look it up.

```
def swap_large(l):
    s = sorted(l)
    d = {k:v for k, v in zip(s, s[1:])}
    
    return [d.get(n, -1) for n in l]

swap_large([5, 7, 3, 2, 8])
# [7, 8, 5, 3, -1]

swap_large([4, 1, 6, -7, -8, 2])
# [6, 2, -1, 1, -7, 4]
```

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what he is actually trying to ask...but great answer :)

Comment: I need to write a function that replaces each number with the next highest number in the list. For each number, you go through and replace each number with the next maximum of the list that you haven't used yet. - I think

Comment: I think this will not work if there are duplicated in the list, right?

Comment: Yes @lebesgue, that was one of the questions asked in the comments. The numbers are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: So if the list is - ```[9, 8, 6, 1]```  what the expected results will be?   Got this - ```[-1, 9, 8, 6]```    Confused by the OP's description...